# Drag and drop in Selenium

Tags: selenium, drag-and-drop

In https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/draganddrop/ I need to drag and drop picture with the text "High Tatras" into Trash section.

```
@Test
void task1() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    try {
        webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        webDriver.get("https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/draganddrop/");

        WebElement from = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gallery\"]/li[1]"));

        WebElement to = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"trash\"]"));

        Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);
        actions.dragAndDrop(from, to).build().perform();
    } finally {
        webDriver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: from and to webelements are inside a frame. Trying switching to the frame and then do draganddrop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the `from` and `to` elements are inside the `iframe`.
So, to access these elements you need to switch into that `iframe` first.
Your code will look as following:

```
@Test
void task1() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    try {
        webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        webDriver.get("https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/draganddrop/");
        
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@rel-title='Photo Manager']//iframe")));

        WebElement from = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gallery']/li[1]"));

        WebElement to = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='trash']"));

        Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);
        actions.dragAndDrop(from, to).build().perform();
    } finally {
        webDriver.close();
    }
}
```